# How data map type find the value by the key?

Tags: dart

I want to know. How did the Map type work when finding the value of a key?
Is this create an index like SQL?
Why these times are same as when I tried this code?
I don't have studied a programming class. Can someone explain in a simple way for me to understand?

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int limit = 1000000;
  Random random = new Random();
  Map<String, int> map = {};
  List<String> list = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    String key = i.toString() + random.nextInt(limit).toString();
    map[key] = i;
    if (i == 0 ||
        i == limit - 1 ||
        i == limit / 2 ||
        i == limit / 4 ||
        i == limit / 10) {
      list.add(key);
      print("$key : $i");
    }
  }
  for (var e in list) {
    print("\n$e");
    int time = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    print(
        "$e : ${map[e]} -> time = ${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - time}");
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
0225402 : 0
100000478677 : 100000
250000355840 : 250000
50000052625 : 500000
999999681585 : 999999

0225402
0225402 : 0 -> time = 0

100000478677
100000478677 : 100000 -> time = 0

250000355840
250000355840 : 250000 -> time = 0

50000052625
50000052625 : 500000 -> time = 0

999999681585
999999681585 : 999999 -> time = 0
```

Comment: The default implementation for a `Map` is a hashtable.  Lookups are ideally O(1) (that is, they take constant time).  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you're asking why all of your results have `time = 0`, `Map` lookups usually should be very fast. (However, I'm not sure offhand if `DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - time` is guaranteed to be computed after `map[e]`.  If you want a specific order, I personally would make the ordering explicit.)

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin, after I used this code.
`int time = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;     int value = map[e]!;     time = TDateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - time;     print("$e : $value , time = $time");`
the `time = ` still be 0.
`The default implementation for a Map is a hashtable.` Thank you for this. I will read about this.

Comment: Is hashtable separate data into buckets and search the data by converting a key with the hash function and then searching the value in this bucket? Am I understanding this right?